# Ionic4 uses Angular routing strategy(by default)?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I read that Ionic4 project(type Angular) uses Angular routing strategy.
What does the `{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }` statement mean? Angular PathLocationStrategy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this covered somewhere but I'm not sure the exact place.

The point of it, if I recall correctly, is to make the Angular routing aware of the slightly different way of doing things that Ionic does.

Which is to automatically wrap it in with the animation direction, and perhaps also to make it aware of the push/pop that Ionic augments the routing with.

However, this is a good opportunity to learn something better than just the answer to this - how to get the answer to these types of questions.

Because Ionic is an open source project you can just dive into the source and see what's going on.

Searching the github repo for `IonicRouteStrategy` delivers us at:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/src/util/ionic-router-reuse-strategy.ts

Which... well... nah I've got no idea haha, but it does often help.

It seems like it just compares the two routes and if they are the same then it approves it.